# closure of nature numbers with finite complement topology

Tags: general-topology

I have an question in general topology ,Find closure of $\Bbb{N}$ with finite complement topology on $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: What do you need help with?  Do you know what a closure is? Do you know what the finite complement topology is? It's hard to help you because you didn't explain what you know and what you don't.

Answer (score 1):

In this setup, a subset of $\mathbb R$ is open if its complement is finite or if it is empty; hence it is closed if it is either finite or the whole space. Since $\overline{\mathbb N}$ cannot be finite, we conclude that $\overline{\mathbb N}=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Better said +1.

Answer (score 0):

The closure is $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed in the finite complement topology if and only if it is finite or is all of $\mathbb{R}$. Now, use that the closure of a set is the intersection of all closed sets containing it.